# Custom Font question

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPad/iPhone app and when I pick a font for my label it does not display the typeface.

For example, I have a Label and have chosen the Handwriting Dakota font, but when I view my .xib it is a standard font... likewise, the font does not show correctly in the simulator.

What do I need to do to make font show in the correct typeface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have your app install your custom font on the device, you are limited to the typefaces that iOS ships with. See [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/) for a list.

Comment: I have a related question also, how come some fonts do not show up in XCode 4?  I select a Label and choose a font but it does not appear in the desired typeface.